go mod download isn't working as expected
I'm new to both docker and go , while trying to containerize a go api , I've remarked something weird .
#1st_stage

FROM golang:1.23rc2-alpine3.20 AS build
WORKDIR /app
ENV GO111MODULE=on
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    go mod download 
RUN apk add --no-cache shadow
RUN useradd -u 1000 go
COPY . .
RUN go build  -o ./binary

#2nd_stage

FROM scratch
ENV GIN_MODE=release
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=build /app/binary .
USER go
CMD ["./binary"]

isn't go mod download the reponsible command for downloading the dependencies (modules) which actually worked as intended , in the first build it took a while to download the modules and in the 2nd build it was pretty fast to work even though i've invalidated the cache of a previous layer (up to here it's okay) , but the build commands outputs to me that it's fetching each module from the go.mod .
I don't get why is this happening , so an explanation will be much appreciated , and i know that my docker file may not be the most optimized so i would appreciate any remarks and tips to improve it .

I believe you placed all of the downloaded modules into the cached folder, which isn't part of the image. And then on a later step, you didn't mount that cached folder. To fix this, mount the folder in both steps:
FROM golang:1.23rc2-alpine3.20 AS build
WORKDIR /app
ENV GO111MODULE=on
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    go mod download 
RUN apk add --no-cache shadow
RUN useradd -u 1000 go
COPY . .
ARG CGO_ENABLED=0
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    go build  -o ./binary

#2nd_stage

FROM scratch
ENV GIN_MODE=release
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=build /app/binary .
USER go
CMD ["./binary"]

I also disabled CGO in this example since you are copying to a scratch base image. This avoids some scenarios that would generate a binary that is not statically linked.

Can u please further explain ur saying "which isn't part of the image" , won't that directory be mounted to the image's File System at the  /go/pkg/mod , so doesn't that make it part of the image? and does the go build normally download the app's dependencies , or it just does that if they weren't downloaded by the go mod donwload. Any clarification would be much appreciated

No. The mount is similar to a volume mount and does not get written to the image filesystem. In the syntax above, that mount only lasts as long as the RUN step. Changes to that mount are available to other builds, but not to the resulting image or steps that do not have the same cached mount.
